# How to display an image on html from database

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I 'm a beginer with spring framework. I insert an image to postgresql database and i want to display it.
the model class is:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] imageTo_display;
    private Long price;
    @ManyToOne
    private Cart cart;


}
```

I think the problem is at image tag but i don't know how to solve it .
and the html is:

```
<th:block th:each="item:${listItems}">
                   <tr>
                       <td>[[${item.id}]]</td>
                       <td>[[${item.name}]]</td>
                       <td>[[${item.price}]]</td>
                       <td>    <img class="s-ava-alone-img" width="150" height="150" th:src="@{${item.imageTo_display}}"></td>
                   </tr>
                   <td>
                       <a class="h4 mr-3" th:href="@{'/users/edit/'+${item.id}}">Edit</a>
                       <a class="h4 mr-3" th:href="@{'/users/delete/' +${item.id}}">Delete</a>
                   </td>
               </th:block>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you should do this is:

1. Create a controller that just returns the `byte[]` array of the image:

   ```
    @GetMapping(value = "/image/{id}")
    public void view(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable(name="id") int id) throws Exception {
      response.setHeader("content-type", "image/jpg");

      Item item = ...; // Get the item based on id;
      OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
      o.write(item.imageTo_display);
      o.close();
    }
   ```
2. Link to your image on the page:

   ```
    <th:block th:each="item: ${listItems}">
        <tr>
             <td th:text="${item.id}" />
             <td th:text="${item.name}" />
             <td th:text="${item.price}" />
             <td><img class="s-ava-alone-img" width="150" height="150" th:src="@{/image/{id}(id=${item.id})}"></td>
        </tr>

        <td>
            <a class="h4 mr-3" th:href="@{/users/edit/{id}(id=${item.id})}">Edit</a>
            <a class="h4 mr-3" th:href="@{/users/delete/{id}(id=${item.id})}">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </th:block>
   ```

Comment: `th:src="@{/image/edit/{id}(id=${item.id})}"` should probably be `th:src="@{/image/{id}(id=${item.id})}"`